# add facebook permissions with azure mobile services?

Tags: android, facebook, azure, permissions, azure-mobile-services

After I have authenticate with Facebook provider on azure mobile services on android application, I want to add some Facebook permissions such as " publish_actions " but I didn't find any example on this topic.

I have found session but I don't know if it is possible to start session after authentication.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Facebook SDK to authenticate to FB, and then using the access token to authenticate with Azure Mobile Services (see [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2014/01/08/using-the-facebook-android-sdk-for-logging-in-to-azure-mobile-services.aspx) for an information on how this can be done), then you should be able to use the FB SDK options themselves to add this new "scope" to the login.

If you're using the web-based UI (i.e., calling `mobileServiceClient.login(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Facebook, callback)`, then you should change the server-side to request additional scopes. If you're using the node.js backend of mobile services, [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2013/12/12/expanded-login-scopes-in-azure-mobile-services.aspx) shows how this can be done - you'll use a custom app setting called `MS_FacebookScope`, and in there you can define which scopes - such as `public_actions` - you want your app to request from the user.